# Keep ESP32 AutoConnect Captive Portal Always Running

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp8266

I have an ESP32 that is running in softap mode with AutoConnect. I'm trying to get the captive portal to always be active, even if the client portion is connected to an AP. The current problem is once the ESP32 establishes the client connection with the router or after the initial timeout period, the captive portal goes away and you have to manually enter the IP address of the of the softap in the web browser.

Is there a setting I'm missing that allows this to happen?

```
  //Config.autoRise = true;
  Config.immediateStart = true;
  Config.portalTimeout = 30 * 1000;
  Config.retainPortal = true;
  Config.title = "ESP32 AP";
  Config.homeUri = "/";
  portal.config(Config);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AutoConnectConfig Config;
    //Config.bootUri=URI; 
    Config.homeUri="/_ac";
    Config.apid = "Vedesp32-1";
   Config.psk  = "vedesp32";
   Config.apip=IPAddress(10,1,1,1);
    //Config.immediateStart = true;
    Config.hostName = "esp32.local";
    Config.title = "NBrowser";
    Config.autoSave = AC_SAVECREDENTIAL_AUTO;
    Config.autoReset = false;
    Config.autoReconnect = true;  
    Config.reconnectInterval = 6; 
    Config.autoRise = true;
    Config.retainPortal = true; 
    Portal.onDetect(atDetect);
    Portal.config(Config);
```

Comment: Config.reconnectInterval = 6;  means 30 X 6 = 180 seconds, it will wait for connection if not post that you will see the portal again.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

```
extern "C" {
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h" 
#include "freertos/timers.h"
}
#include <WiFiClient.h>

#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <AutoConnect.h>


#define IND 2
#define BUZZER 5
#define SWITCH_ON "True"
#define SWITCH_OFF "False"

#define CREDENTIAL_OFFSET 0

const char* URI = "/_ac";


TimerHandle_t wifiReconnectTimer;
AutoConnect Portal;


void pinInit() {

 
  pinMode(BUZZER, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IND, OUTPUT);

}

void connectToWifi() {

  Serial.println("Connecting to Wi-Fi... ->");
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(5000);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
}



void WiFiEvent(WiFiEvent_t event) {
  Serial.printf("[WiFi-event] event: %d\n", event);
  switch (event) {
    case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP:
      Serial.println("WiFi connected");
      Serial.println("IP address: ");
      Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
      digitalWrite(BUZZER, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(IND, HIGH);
      break;
    case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED:
      Serial.println("WiFi lost connection");
       digitalWrite(IND, LOW);
      xTimerStart(wifiReconnectTimer, 0);
      break;
  }
}



  






 
  void setup() {

    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println();
    pinInit();
    digitalWrite(IND, LOW);
    
    wifiReconnectTimer = xTimerCreate("wifiTimer", pdMS_TO_TICKS(2000), pdFALSE, (void*)0, reinterpret_cast<TimerCallbackFunction_t>(connectToWifi));

    WiFi.onEvent(WiFiEvent);
    

    
    AutoConnectConfig Config;
    //Config.bootUri=URI; 
    Config.homeUri="/_ac";
    Config.apid = "Ved";
   Config.psk  = "vedesp32";
   Config.apip=IPAddress(10,1,1,1);
    //Config.immediateStart = true;
    Config.hostName = "esp32.local";
    Config.title = "NBrowser";
    Config.autoSave = AC_SAVECREDENTIAL_AUTO;
    Config.autoReset = false;     // Not reset the module even by intentional disconnection using AutoConnect menu.
    Config.autoReconnect = true;  // Reconnect to known access points.
    Config.reconnectInterval = 6; // Reconnection attempting interval is 3[min].
    Config.autoRise = true;
    Config.retainPortal = true;   // Keep the captive portal open.
    Portal.onDetect(atDetect);
    Portal.config(Config); 
  
  // Start
  if (Portal.begin()) {
    Serial.println("WiFi connected: " + WiFi.localIP().toString());
    digitalWrite(IND, HIGH);
  }
    connectToWifi();

    

    

  }


bool atDetect(IPAddress& softapIP) {
  Serial.println("Captive portal started, SoftAP IP:" + softapIP.toString());
  return true;
}


  void loop() {
   
       Portal.handleClient();

  }
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.